# Как сделать перезапись json файла с заменой значений [Java]

Tags: java

Как сделать перезапись json файла в котором находятся строки с большими названиям и значениями? 
Вообще мне требуется чтобы json файл перезаписывался и изменял значение строки которое я указал в коде программы на другое мне нужно изменять только определенные строки с значениями не все перезапись должна идти в один и тот-же файл
Строки в моем файле json > **{63ad9d34f3503826e5f649ae6b7ac92c:1, 
                        "3074ce7ffaea0148826be423a2ef6b04":1}**
Строки не должны затрагиваться только значения у меня это цифра 1 также у меня присутствуют в файле json строки с значениями true, false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм примерно такой:

- Прочитать файл.
- Получить из прочитанного объект (при помощи [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), например)
- Изменить значения в объекте
- Сохранить объект в файл

Конкретные примеры кода с применением Jackson можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial#jackson-json-8211-edit-json-document)